# Can a big enough Giant travel many lightyears in just a few seconds?

Tags: time, faster-than-light, distance

We, as humans, given our height and size, view the world from the same general perspective. An ant, on the other hand, will understand the same world in a completely different way, given how limited their knowledge and experiences can be. When we spend a couple seconds taking a step out onto our front yard, it might have taken a microbe years to travel that same distance (assuming it can survive and all that). To the ants living in your front yard, your back yard might just be the "edge of the Universe" for them, let alone the other side of the city or continent. For an organism smaller than even Planck's length, assuming such thing exists, then Planck's length might just be the limit of their world, and who knows what's going on down there.

Let's reverse that thinking and apply it to something that's bigger than us. Now, we are playing as the "ants" or the "organisms smaller than Planck's length". A bear, for example, can travel farther than a human given the same amount of time, and what we view as "further apart" might seem "closer" to the bear. To something as big as a planet, the Earth might be its "front yard" and the moon its "back yard". For something much much bigger, the size of a galaxy, lets say, what would be its "other side of the city"? By "taking a step", that thing would travel a distance worth of many light years in just a few seconds, right?

Comment: Have you studied the reasons why nothing can travel faster than light, and have you tried to pinpoint a step in the  usual reasoning which might not apply to an extremely large creature?

Answer (score 1):

> By "taking a step", that thing would travel a distance worth of many light years in just a few seconds, right?

**No**

The signals from your brain to your muscles to tell them to move travel at some speed that's smaller than the speed of light, and even when the muscles actually move, they still can't move faster than light. Your hypothetical galaxy-sized organism would take a hundred thousand years to decide to move a limb, and that limb would not move faster than the speed of light.

Comment: The individual atoms in the giant's body cannot move that fast.